# homomorphism between same length modules can't be surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two indecomposable $R$-modules with $\ell(M_1)=\ell(M_2)$, where >$\ell$ denotes the length of a module.
> Let $f: M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ be a non bijective homomorphism of $R$-modules.

Is it true that $f$ can't be surjective?

Comment: What is $M{}{}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey sorry, i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is onto.
We have $$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Ker}f\rightarrow M_1\rightarrow \operatorname{M_2}\rightarrow 0$$
is a short exact sequence. Since $\ell$ is additive, we get $\ell(\operatorname{Ker}f)0\implies \operatorname{Ker}f=0$ 
 So $f$ is injective as well.

**Note:** I am assuming that in your question both $M_1$ and $M_2$ have finite length.

Comment: Yes, $M_1$ and $M_2$ indeed have finite length. Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot :) I don't quite understand how you concluded that $\ell$(Ker$f)$=0?

Comment: By additivity, $\ell(Ker(f)) = \ell(M_1) - \ell(M_2) = 0$ since the lengths are the same. I think it's also worth noting that indecomposability isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you and noted!:)